# Show a loading page when data is fetching - React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have 2 parts of the page, left side is the collection of Ids and second part is displaying the data.

First time when the page is loading all the data (of all the Ids
) is displayed. But user can select only 1 id and can see the data of that particular id but it takes time to fetch the data. So between the time of clicking the id and displaying the data - the page shows the previous data (which is fairly confusing) and suddenly the data is changed after the fetch is completed. I want to show the loading page when the id is clicked till the data appears.

How to do that.

On Id select below function is executed and then it goes to the reducer for dispatch action.

```
onIdSelection(key, obj) {
        if (key && key.id) {
            this.props.dispatch(actions.fetchDataActionCreator(key.id));
        }
    }
```

In the reducer:

```
export const fetchDataActionCreator = (siteId) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch({
            type: START_FETCH_DEVICES,
            payload: api.get({
                url: '/api/ndp/v1/collector/telemetry/sites/' + siteId + '/devices',
                config: {
                    apiPrefix: 'none'
                }
            }).then(payload => dispatch({
                type: FINISH_FETCH_DEVICES,
                meta: {siteId},
                payload})
            )
        });
    };
};
```

In the reducer:

```
 case START_FETCH_DEVICES:
            return {...state, dataLoading: true};
 case FINISH_FETCH_DEVICES:
            return {...state, dataLoading: false, payload: action.payload};
```

On the data side:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const {dataUpdated} = nextProps;
        if (dataUpdated) {
            this.props.dispatch(actions.fetchDataActionCreator(this.props.id));
        }
    }
```

Here when I get the data in the nextProps - there is the whole data not on the Id selected.

How to just show the "loading" div till the data is ready for display.

Comment: Are you using any async middleware with your redux? Common examples include redux-thunk, redux-saga, redux-observable.

Comment: I don't usually use Redux, but in a React component I usually do a `setState({loading: true})` before making the request, and when the data comes back from the api I do another `setState({loading: false})` so that I can render the appropriate stuff in the `render` method. Maybe create a new reducer that keeps track of if something is loading, and update it after you get the data back.

Comment: Yes I also do the same. but the issue is how can I get the value of loading in the data side. It comes after the fetch is done. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You should add split FetchData action into 2 actions:
1. First `type: START_FETCH_DEVICES`
2. Second `type: FINISH_FETCH_DEVICES`

To orchestrate dispatching these two action use action creators.

For example

```
export const fetchDataActionCreator = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch ({type: START_FETCH_DEVICES});
    api.get({
        url: '/api/ndp/v1/id/' + id,
        config: {
            apiPrefix: 'none'
        }
    }).then(payload => dispatch({
        type: FINISH_FETCH_DEVICES,
        meta: {id},
        payload})  
    // I'm not sure that api.get can return Promise, but most async fetch api do so
    )
}
```

Now you have `fetchDataActionCreator` as action creator which returns function tacking `dispatch` as first argument. When connecting your component to Redux use `bindActionCreators` to properly wrap `fetchDataActionCreator`.

Reducer should set some variable in state to notify app that data is loading.

For example

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case START_FETCH_DEVICES:
            return {...state, dataLoading: true}
        case FINISH_FETCH_DEVICES:
            return {...state, dataLoading: false, payload: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And your component can display Loading message when `state.dataLoading` is `true`

Comment: I would suggest to add another `action` `FETCH_DEVICES_ERROR` to set `{ dataLoading: false, error: true }` to inform the user that something went wrong.

Comment: I tried this but now the data is not changing at all.

Comment: what do you mean by data not changing? check redux logs and update your findings in the question.

Comment: @VishalSharma I have updated the code. I implemented acoording to this answer but the issue is the data in the this.props returns the whole data of the Ids not the only selected one.